# X11VNC connection ends randomly

Tags: networking, 18.04, vnc

I have a X11VNC server running on a local machine in my LAN. In the past month, it has been "randomly" kicking my client out of session as I use it. I'm not certain as to how to debug the error and I can't seem to find a similar issue via search.

Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
X11VNC (installed and running for over a year)
Multiple clients tried and failed

Comment: I would check if the process is still running on server machine (`pgrep -l vnc`) and if the connection is stable with (`ping -f lanServerIpAddr`, read `man ping`).

Comment: The VNC process is still running and the ping appears to be stable. Actually, I am able to get back into the machine in about 5 seconds after being booted. When I get in, nothing appears to be amiss. Thanks!